# Is local maximizer of a convex function a subset of global maximizer?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given two convex function $f(x): R^2 \to R$ and $g(a, b) = f(a) + f(b): R^2 \times R^2 \to R$.

And a convex compact set $Z \subset R^2$.

We have $X^* = \{x^*\} = \text{argmax}_{x \in Z} f(x)$.

And $(A^*, B^*) = \{ (a^*, b^*) \} = \text{argmax}_{(a, b) \in Z \times Z; a+b \in Z} g(a, b)$.

Would $\cup (X^* \cap A^*, X^* \cap B^* ) != \emptyset $ hold ?

Comment: Why are you assuming that there is only one $\operatorname{argmax}$?

Comment: Because my explicit form of f and Z actually provides one maximum, but you are right, i should probably use intersection is not null.

Comment: $x\mapsto \|x\|_2^2$ has $4$ maximisers on $[-1,1]^2$. The maximisers of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ on same are all points on the boundary.

Comment: Yes, i didn’t share my explicit form of f and Z here, but as i have replied, to adapt to the general form, the $\in$ would be generalize to $\cup (X^* \cap A^*, X^* \cap B^*) != \emptyset$

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. You have $\operatorname{argmax}_{a,b \in Z} g(a,b)  = \operatorname{argmax}_{a \in Z} f(a) \times \operatorname{argmax}_{a \in Z} f(a)$.

Comment: There is a constrain for $a+b \in Z$

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: No worries, thanks for looking into this and help me clear things out :)